# how to change height of ellipse in radial gradient in css for background property

Tags: css

When i create background gradient like this:

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 59%,#ededed 100%);
```

I get ellipse that is inside the div, and conform to shape of div. So if div is large in height then ellipse would be stretched vertically. If div is a square then ellipse would be like a circle. That's fine, i want to control height of ellipse.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: i am asking how transform ellipse inside the circle like scale vertically. I know i can position it, but i couldn't find a way to stretch it with px or % values.

Comment: So, For example you want only the half of the gradient to be visible?

Comment: ill post a picture to show what i mean

Comment: Yea that would make more sense.

Comment: it'll make it easier to understand..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a div with overflow set to hidden, and a div inside of it absolutely positioned with a fixed height.

```css
#outer {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
#inner {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works...and is clever. but isn't there a way to do it right with gradial property.

Comment: There might be some support, however how many browsers support it could be an issue. See this article to try out gradient positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

Comment: The examples, where the radial gradients are positioned in different section of the div.

Comment: ok but that's not changing the vertical height of gradient..are they?

Answer (score 9):

The exact question can be addressed by combining the last 2 answers: circle gradient and adjusting the background size.

Something like this:

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, white 0%, red 50%, black 100%);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position: 0% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I find it less of a hassle than nested divs, and by playing with the background-position and size values, you can get some pretty cool effects!

Comment: didn't think ill see the solution to this problem

Comment: Better late than never (:

Answer (score 3):

I hate to revive such an old post, but I couldn't help but notice that none of the answers here give what I would consider to be the "correct" solution: sizing the *gradient itself.* So, I may as well add my answer onto the pile just in case anybody else finds their way here looking for radial-gradient-related answers, like I did.

You can define a radial gradient not only using `<shape>`, but **also `<position>` and `<size>` values**. This was the case [even before this question was asked](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-images-20120112/#ltsize), so I'm not sure how that was missed.

So, I would simply define the gradient as a really, really tall ellipse. No extra `background-size` property needed:

```css
.gradient {
  width: 30em;
  margin: .5em;
  border: .2em solid black;
}

#one {
  height: 10em;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 20%, red, blue);
}

#two {
  height: 25em;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 1000%, #ffffff 0%, #a0a0a0 80%);
}

.gradient div {
  color: white;
  background: #00000080;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient" id="one">
  <div>With 20% ellipse height</div>
</div>

<div class="gradient" id="two">
  <div>With 1000% ellipse height</div>
</div>
```

Granted, I think the desired effect in the original post looks close enough to linear that you could just define it as a `linear-gradient(gray, white, gray)`, but that's beside the point...

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the background dimensions and position:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, white 0%, red 100%);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position: 0% 50%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yL4razfx/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `circle` instead of `ellipse`:

### Demo on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/be3d7816d5550821c9ce)

```
.rect2 {
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 59%, #dcdcdc 100%);
}
```

Comment: yes but it doesn't give you just control of vertical height, can you make circle height bigger than width..can you stretch circle.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - Yes, check out the updated answer. I've changed the demo as well.